# Fn function always on while using keyboard with no Fn key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, function-keys

Using thinkpad X270 - there is a Fn key on the default laptop keyboard but I'm using external usb connected keyboard in my work station, the problem is that by default, the Fn key is on and can be toggeled of with `Fn + Esc` but the external keyboard does not have the Fn button so I can't turn it off and when I turn it off on the laptop keyboard it does not affect the external one. Is there any way to either completely disable the Fn mode function keys? I find them kind of useless anyways or at least swap the default to the Fn mode being disabled?

Basically, I just want to use the default shortcuts like F2 - rename file, F5 reload etc. ...

I remember I was able to somehow remove the Fn mode on my previous Ubuntu install but I can't figure out how I did it back then.

Comment: First paste this into your terminal: `sudo apt-get install screenkey`, the instructions to set it up are [here.](https://gitlab.com/screenkey/screenkey)
You should be able to see exactly what keys are being inputted. Attach a screenshot of what it looks like. You should be able to see what keyboard is doing it.